# WPF trouble with maximizing text

Tags: wpf, maximize

I'm having a bit of trouble. I want my page to maximize by the text inside the textbox, but can only get it to maximize by the border of the textbox. Can anyone help me?

It's very important to get this right. I have to get the leftmost pixel just as far from the border as the rightmost pixel in the rotated text.

I postet the XAML-code for "First line" on the bottom, the code for "Another line" is just fixed size and location, so I cut that part out.

```
<Viewbox Height="3000" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Width="Auto">
    <TextBox Text="First line" BorderThickness="0" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  >
        <TextBox.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="-35"/>
        </TextBox.LayoutTransform>
    </TextBox>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Set Height="NaN", is it what you want?

Comment: Setting Height="NaN" still maximize the textbox border to fit the viewbox, but I want a way to maximize so that its the text itself that is maximized inside a border or viewbox. If it's easier I can use a bitmap or label or whatever, as long as its the text that just touches the border of the page, not the frame around the text.

Comment: Look at the image linked. The top line is what I get, the bottom line is what I want.

http://i1290.photobucket.com/albums/b522/xenovel/lines.png

Answer (score 0):

Editted: You should set your textbox to be a child of a border, set the margin and then rotate the border (instead of the textbox).(see the comments);

```
<Window ....
    Height="600"
    Width="400">
<Grid>
    <Viewbox 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
             VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
       <Border Background="AliceBlue">
            <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True"
                     Margin="-4"
                     BorderThickness="0"
                     Background="Transparent">

                <TextBox.Text>
                    First line and more and more ansd
                </TextBox.Text>
            </TextBox>
            <Border.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-35" />
            </Border.LayoutTransform>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but depending on the length of the text (and then also the size of the font), the text will do outside the boundries of the page as the size of the text is getting smaller.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer. I think you should set your textbox to be a child of a border, set the margin and then rotate the border (instead of the textbox). (use Background color of the border, to set the margin correctly)

Comment: This way is way better than I've made so far, but still not quite there. Still needs the leftmost pixel to be as far from the edge as the rightmost. It looks good for most texts now, but som letters quite dont fit. Like the text "A j" will have the "j" very close to the right side, but the "A" far from the left side

Comment: When text="Aj" I could get the best by Margin="-4,-6.1,-4.8,-2". If the positioning depends on what comes first and ..., maybe you should deal with them problematically. I mean handling TextChanged event.

Comment: So I guess there's no easy way of doing this. Either I have to deal with the fact that my texts wont be centered the way I want, or I have to program for every first and last letter. Too bad... Is it possible to create a transparent image and then go through each pixel and crop image for first / last pixel thats not transparent?

Comment: no need to program for every first and last letter. e.g. B,E,H,I,K,L,M,N,R,U,W,X,Y,Z start from top-left point and end at bottom right point. So when text starts and ends with them, there is no need to change anything. letters like j,O, ... might need special treatment.

Comment: Yes, of course. But then again, a simple "copy/paste"-solution was what I was hoping for ;-) But thanks!